# How do I give myself an item that can only be placed on a block with a certain damage value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently in the process of making a custom map and I want to add blocks that can only be placed on a certain colour clay.

This is the command I tried using.

```
/give @p cobblestone 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["hardened_stained_clay"],Damage:3}
```

However, even with this command the cobblestone can be placed on any colour of stained clay. What command can I use for placing only on a certain block?

Comment: Texenox is right that you're currently putting the damage value onto the cobblestone. I don't think there is a way to only allow placing a block on blocks with a certain damage value. Unfortunately you may just need to change your map's block palette to account for this.

Comment: The concept of damage values no longer exists in 1.13

Answer (score 8):

**Unfortunately, the CanPlaceOn tag does not support Damage values as of yet.** The syntax of that tag will only accept an array of strings that correspond to block names, therefore you cannot make the item be placed only on a specific colour, only hardened clay in general.

Also, you are currently trying to set a Damage value to the block to be placed rather than the block it should be placed *on*.