# A Redstone Torch That Can Only Be Placed On Green Wool In Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a command block that gives the player a redstone torch that can be placed only on green wool, I know how to use the Can Be Placed Component But I don't know how to add the green wool data value that makes it green.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give myself an item that can only be placed on a block with a certain damage value?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228524/how-do-i-give-myself-an-item-that-can-only-be-placed-on-a-block-with-a-certain-d)

Comment: While the question linked is more about a lack of damage value support in a command block command, the answer to that question still supports this one.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, adding the data value to the `"can_place_on"` tag is not possible.