# error trying to put a command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi (im spanish sorry for my english) im try to put this command in minecraft but not works, i need place a lever in chiseled stone bricks.

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stonebrick 3"]}
```

im in 1.8.9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give myself an item that can only be placed on a block with a certain damage value?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228524/how-do-i-give-myself-an-item-that-can-only-be-placed-on-a-block-with-a-certain-d)

Comment: Seems to be impossible.